# Is this the way to check the ip of a server?

Tags: linux, networking

```
ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*'127.0.0.1'
```

I tried whitelisting an IP, because I am making an ajax call on the frontend and then the backend makes an API call, but I got the error "iprestriction: the ip wasn't whitelisted", so I was wondering why, and running the command above gave me 6 different ips, so whitelisting them all should be fix it? Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding something?

I was told only one needs to be whitelisted, but I am not sure why. I am guessing there's only 1 real ip, but what are the other ips for, and how can a server have multiple ips? Because the ips don't seem to be the subnet ips, but the externally accessible ips.

Comment: What is the output of "ip addr show" ? Can you describe the scenario better?  If you are trying to whitelist the external IP associated with your local NAT'ed network on a remote server you likely need to dind the external ip address wjich is on your router or an upstream device. Browsing to whatismyip.com normally tells you this.  To do it programatically you may need to write a script on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how I check the IP of a server is `hostname -i`, which gives just the IP
if you want more information about all the IPs on your system (like the loopback, etc) you could use `ifconfig` (like you're currently doing) or just `ip a`.  Both should give you the same info and you could determine from that which IP(s) you are interested in whitelisting.

Answer (score -1):

Would you mind showing the 6 IP's to us? More information about your scenario is appreciated. Are both machines in the same LAN? You know about private and public IP adresses..?

How can a server/client have different IP's, mmh, it's up to you to configure your ethernet interface**s** with multiple addresses.
Anyways, there are several ways of reading the calling IP to your firewalled host.
Go, read about commands like: tcpdump, ping, ip, host

PS: your string is missing the closing single closing quote

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).